# Algebraic identity arising from coupon collectors problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, coupon-collector

Prove the following identity:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{n \choose k}{k}= 1+\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \dots \frac 1 n \tag{1}$$

EDIT: Equation (1) above is proved via integration by @donaldsplutterwit. And I suppose this could lead to the equivalent identity below. However, still want to see if there is a more direct way to prove it.

Or equivalently, prove that when $n$ is even (see my attempt for why equivalent):

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}-1^{k+1}\frac{n-1 \choose k}{n-k} = \frac 2 n$$

---

My attempt:

I denote $S_n$ as the LHS of equation (1) and try to show $S_n-S_{n-1}=\frac 1 n$

Let

$$S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{{n \choose k}}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{{n \choose k}}{k}+\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n}\tag{2}$$

Now,

$${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{n-k} {n-1 \choose k} = \left(1+\frac{k}{n-k}\right){n-1\choose k}$$

Substituting into equation (2):

$$S_n = S_{n-1} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{{n-1 \choose k}}{n-k}+\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n}$$

We require:
$$S_n-S_{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{{n-1 \choose k}}{n-k}+\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n}=\frac1 n$$

This would imply:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{{n-1 \choose k}}{n-k} = \begin{cases}\frac2 n, & n\%2=0\\
    0,    & n\%2=1\end{cases}$$

The second case is easy to see since if $n$ is odd, the $k$ th term of the summation above becomes:

$$t_k = -1^{k+1}\frac{n-1 \choose k}{n-k}=-1^{k+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

And

$$t_{n-k} = -1^{n-k+1}\frac{n-1 \choose n-k}{k} = -1^k \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!k!}=-t_k$$

So, every $t_k$ term is matched with a $t_{n-k}$ terms and they all cancel. Haven't managed to make progress on the case when $n$ is even.

---

Where did this identity come from? I was studying the [Coupon collector's problem](http://mat.uab.cat/matmat/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf) and for the case when all coupons have equal probabilities of being collected, we get the average number of draws until all coupons are collected:

$$E(X) = n \sum_i \frac 1 i$$

If the coupons have different probabilities given by $p_i$ we get:

$$E(X) = \sum_i \frac 1 p_i - \sum_{i<j}\frac 1 {p_i+p_j}+\dots +(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{p_1+\dots +p_n}$$

Substituting $p_i=\frac 1 n$ for all $i$ into the second equation and substituting into the first leads to equation (1).

Comment: Great job asking the question, but please use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%5Cleft(-1%5Cright)%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1) to find prior art next time! This is one of the most popular exercises on binomial coefficients around.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, didn't know about Approach0.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - would still like to see a more direct proof of the second identity in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{k}=\int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
The sum becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \binom{n}{k} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k+1} \int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx\\
&=&  \int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-x)^{n}}{x}dx. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute $u=1-x$.

Edit: A similar trick can be used to show the second identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n-k}=\int_0^1 x^{n-k-1}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
The sum becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n-k} \binom{n-1}{k} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} (-1)^{k+1} \int_0^1 x^{n-k-1}dx \\
&=& (-1)^n \int_0^1 \left( (1-x)^{n-1} +(-1)^n x^{n-1}\right) dx. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, would still like to see a proof of the second identity if possible.